# Multiple interfaces in single file

Tags: java, interface

I was just wondering if you can limit the number of interface files on a project. Couple of projects i work with have dozen of interfaces with nothing special in them, and i was thinking can you write all interfaces in single file ? and in specific class point to interface needed ?? i.e:

```
//interface file
interface InterfaceOne {

}
interface InterfaceTwo{

}
//foo file
public class foo implements InterfaceTwo{
   public void foo {
         //....
   }
}
//foo1 file
public class foo1 implements InterfaceOne{
   public void foo {
        //....
    }
}
```

or something similar ?

Comment: method cannot "implements" interface. pls fix your codes.

Comment: @Kent yes you are right, corrected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can fill a file with interfaces, but those interfaces cannot be `public`. Thus, they can only be accessible from the package they are defined in. If that's OK with you, you can collect your interfaces into a single file.

Note that this might make your interface definitions harder to find.

Comment: I was aware that not making interface public will unable other classes outside the package to implement it. But anyway this is still good news for me, as it means i can refactor the code and save about 30% in 'space'

Comment: @MaciejCygan: good to hear. Just as long as you name the file something obvious, like `Interfaces.java`, I suspect nobody will complain too loudly ;)

Comment: Why not have an emtpy public class with with multiple public interfaces inside?

Comment: This totally makes sense if you have sub-interfaces, I guess I'd like to know if you can nest them instead of /in addition to using extend.